# Webix window - autoadjust

Tags: window, autosize, webix

I am new to webix and have a problem with ui.window!

For me the window *never* adjusts to the parent HTML element. :(

I want the window to have the same width and height as the parent (100%).

What am I dowing wrong?

See code in Webix Snippets: http://webix.com/snippet/c5fe5e96

**According to the documentation:**

"Window Sizing and Positioning

The must-have parameters for the window are width and height. If you don't set [them], the window [...] will occupy the whole screen."

http://docs.webix.com/desktop__window.html

"adjust - adjusts the component to the size of the parent html container"

http://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.popup_adjust.html

Answer (score 2):

Window and Popup widgets are working for the whole app, they are not using container and can't use .adjust as well.

You can size the Window to the document by using fullscreen option

```
var popup = webix.ui({
    view: "window",
    fullscreen:true,
```

http://webix.com/snippet/93a5e3ba

or by using the complex position property

```
var popup = webix.ui({
    view: "window",
    position:function(state){
      state.left = state.top = 10;
      state.width = state.maxWidth - 20;
      state.height = state.maxHeight-20;
    },
```

http://webix.com/snippet/164a3955

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have found a solution that makes the window inherit its size from the parent container.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to make the window inherit the size of the HTML container by getting the HTML container size by using getNode() and then using setPosition, config.width, config.height and resize().

See example below. 
http://webix.com/snippet/056b9610